# How to restrict pull request deployment for document changes in Travis CI?

Tags: github, travis-ci, pull-request

I am currently working on Travis CI automation build process. I am stuck with a requirement.

Contributors are sending pull requests for document changes (like readme.md file change or minor code changes which doesn't require a build process). My Automation script starting the build process for every pull request.

Is there any option to restrict this and provide flexibility to owner/approver to pick the Pull requests as per his/her choice.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to [trigger the travis build only for a specific branch](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Building-Specific-Branches). Meaning that PR for doc would be merged in another branch (and merge later to the main branch, triggering only one fake build, instead of multiple ones at each doc PR)

Another possibility is to [implement a complex Travis build](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Implementing-Complex-Build-Steps) in which you run a test which triggers the build if no doc PR is detected:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ev
bundle exec rake:units
if [ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" = "false" ]; then
    bundle exec rake test:integration
fi
```

Finally, one could consider having the doc in a separate repo, referenced by the main repo as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

I would test option 2 first.

Comment: Re-writing my question based on @VonC 2 options.. In my case, the master repository is having only master branch and always PR's comes to the master branch. I can't restrict the build deployment specific to branch in my case.

Comment: We are using Go language and docker environment... The above example is given for the ruby project. Could you please help me how to achieve this.